# How to load "opencv_java249.dll" at web service(such as GAE , SAE)

Tags: java, web-services, opencv

My program runs well at my personal computer,however,when I deploy it to the SAE (http://sae.sina.com.cn/) it can't work.It seems like that

```
System.load("E:/test/opencv_java249.dll");
```

can'n be executed well.

Here is my code.

```
package demo;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.features2d.*;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.ml.*;

import com.sina.sae.util.SaeUserInfo;

public class opencvtest {

private int number=81+1;    
private int kind=9;
private int ID[];
private int flowerNumber[];
private String flowerName[];
private String fileAddress[];
private String MaxscoreFlower[];
private double score[];
private double totalscore[];

private SVM mysiftsvm;
private SVM mycolorsvm;

private String Path="D://tomcat//apache-tomcat-6.0.43//webapps//test//";
//private String Path="http://identification-hellodomain.stor.sinaapp.com//";
public int getKind() {
    return kind;
}


public void setKind(int kind) {
    this.kind = kind;
}


public String[] getFlowerName() {
    return flowerName;
}


public void setFlowerName(String[] flowerName) {
    this.flowerName = flowerName;
}

public String  getMaxscoreFlower() {
    return MaxscoreFlower[0];
}

public opencvtest()
{

}


public opencvtest(String testPicture,int flagsql,int flagtrain)
{
    //System.loadLibrary("opencv_java249");

    System.load("E:/test/opencv_java249.dll");

    if(flagsql==1)
    sqlConnect();
    else
    sqlConnectOnline();

    int ans=0;
    if(flagtrain==1)
    ans=(int)useSvm(testPicture);
    else
    ans=(int)useSvmbyfile(testPicture);

    String svmflower=flowerName[ans*9];
    System.out.println("svm计算结果： 第"+ans+"种花："+svmflower);

    /*
    compute(testPicture);
    System.out.println("颜色比较计算结果：");
    System.out.println("第1种花："+MaxscoreFlower[0]);
    System.out.println("第2种花："+MaxscoreFlower[1]);
    System.out.println("第3种花："+MaxscoreFlower[2]);
    */
    judgeName(svmflower);


}

//siftsvm的训练结果与颜色比较的结果的综合
public void judgeName(String svmflower)
{
    if(svmflower==MaxscoreFlower[0])
    {

    }
    else if(svmflower==MaxscoreFlower[1])
    {
        String temp=MaxscoreFlower[0];
        MaxscoreFlower[0]=MaxscoreFlower[1];
        MaxscoreFlower[1]=temp;

    }
    else if(svmflower==MaxscoreFlower[2])
    {
        String temp=MaxscoreFlower[1];
        MaxscoreFlower[1]=MaxscoreFlower[2];
        MaxscoreFlower[2]=temp;
    } else
    {
        MaxscoreFlower[2]=MaxscoreFlower[1];
        MaxscoreFlower[1]=MaxscoreFlower[0];
        MaxscoreFlower[0]=svmflower;
    }
   System.out.println("最终匹配结果");
   System.out.println("第一名："+MaxscoreFlower[0]);
   System.out.println("第二名："+MaxscoreFlower[1]);
   System.out.println("第三名："+MaxscoreFlower[2]);
}

//训练测试数据并预测
public double useSvm(String testPicture)
{
    mysiftsvm=new SVM();
    mysiftsvm.init();
    getTrainingfiles();
    double ans=predict(testPicture);

    return ans;
}

//通过已训练出的数据进行预测
public double useSvmbyfile(String testPicture)
{
    mysiftsvm=new SVM();
    mysiftsvm.init();
    mysiftsvm.classifier=new CvSVM();
    mysiftsvm.classifier.load("D://tomcat//apache-tomcat-6.0.43//webapps//test//trainmodel");
    //mysiftsvm.classifier.load("http://identification-hellodomain.stor.sinaapp.comtest//trainmodel");
    double ans=predict(testPicture);

    return ans;
}

//获得训练图片sift特征矩阵并加入到训练机中
public void getTrainingfiles()
{
    mysiftsvm.svm_trainingimages = new Mat();   
    mycolorsvm.svm_trainingimages = new Mat();  
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i<number-1; i++)
    {

            j=1+i/9;
            Mat img=new Mat();                                              //创建连续存储的img
            img.create(new Size(554,128), CvType.CV_32FC1);
            Mat img2=new Mat();                                                                             

//读入不连续存储的灰度img2
            img2 = sift(fileAddress[i+1]); 
            Imgproc.resize(img2, img2, new Size(554,128));
            System.out.println(fileAddress[i+1]+":  width="+img2.width()+"      height:"+img2.height());        
            img2.copyTo(img);                               //将不连续存储的img2复制到连续存储的img                                    


            img = img.reshape(1, 1);                                        //特征向量以行来存储!
            img.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32FC1);                //转换为CV_32FC1类型
            mysiftsvm.svm_trainingimages.push_back(img);                    //加入到训练数据中

            Mat m=Mat.ones(new Size(1, 1), CvType.CV_32FC1);
            m=m.mul(m, j);
            mysiftsvm.svm_classes.push_back(m);

            img.release();
            img2.release();
            m.release();
    }

    mysiftsvm.svm_trainingimages.copyTo(mysiftsvm.svm_trainingdata);            //训练数据写到svm_trainingdata中
    mysiftsvm.svm_trainingdata.convertTo(mysiftsvm.svm_trainingdata, CvType.CV_32FC1);//转换格式
    mysiftsvm.svm_classes.copyTo(mysiftsvm.svm_traininglabels);                     //标签数据写到svm_traininglabels中

    System.out.println(mysiftsvm.svm_trainingimages.toString());
    System.out.println(mysiftsvm.svm_trainingdata.toString());
    System.out.println(mysiftsvm.svm_classes.toString());
    System.out.println(mysiftsvm.svm_traininglabels.toString());


                                                                                            //创建svm：classifier
    mysiftsvm.classifier = new CvSVM(mysiftsvm.svm_trainingdata, mysiftsvm.svm_traininglabels, new Mat(), new Mat(), mysiftsvm.svm_params);
    System.out.println(mysiftsvm.classifier.get_support_vector_count());
    System.out.println(mysiftsvm.svm_traininglabels.toString());
    System.out.println(mysiftsvm.svm_traininglabels.dump());
    mysiftsvm.classifier.save("trainmodel");

} 

//预测测试图片的种类
public double predict(String testPicture)
{
    Mat sample=sift(testPicture);
    Imgproc.resize(sample, sample, new Size(554,128));
    Mat img=new Mat();                                      
    img.create(new Size(554,128), CvType.CV_32FC1);
    sample.copyTo(img);                                     
    img = img.reshape(1, 1);                                        //特征向量以行来存储!
    img.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32FC1);                //转换为CV_32FC1类型
    double ans=mysiftsvm.classifier.predict(img);
    return ans;
}


public void compute(String testPicture)
{
    for (int i=1;i<number;i++)
    {
        //double score1=sift(fileAddress[i],testPicture);
        score[i]=compareHist(fileAddress[i],testPicture);
        System.out.println("第"+i+"张图片:"+"颜色得分： "+score[i]);
    }
    totalscore =new double[kind+1];
    for(int i=1;i<=kind;i++)
    {
        totalscore[i]=0;
        int index =(i-1)*kind;
        int j;
        for(j=1;j<=kind;j++)
            totalscore[i]+=score[index+j];

    }
    for (int i=1;i<=kind;i++)
        System.out.println("第"+i+"种花总分"+totalscore[i]);
    for (int i=1;i<=kind;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<=kind;j++)
            if(totalscore[i]<totalscore[j])
            {
                double temp=totalscore[j];
                totalscore[j]=totalscore[i];
                totalscore[i]=temp;

                String temp2=flowerName[j*kind];
                flowerName[j*kind]=flowerName[i*kind];
                flowerName[i*kind]=temp2;

            }
    }



    MaxscoreFlower[0]=flowerName[1*kind];
    MaxscoreFlower[1]=flowerName[2*kind];
    MaxscoreFlower[2]=flowerName[3*kind];


}

//sift特征矩阵的比较
public double sift(String trainPicture,String testPicture)
{
    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );

    Mat test_mat1  = Highgui.imread(trainPicture);
    Mat test_mat2 = Highgui.imread(testPicture);

    Mat desc1 = new Mat();
    Mat desc2 = new Mat();

    FeatureDetector fd1 = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);//创建特征描述子
    FeatureDetector fd2 = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);//创建特征描述子
    MatOfKeyPoint mkp1 =new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint mkp2 =new MatOfKeyPoint();

    fd1.detect(test_mat1, mkp1);
    fd2.detect(test_mat2, mkp2);
    DescriptorExtractor de1 = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SIFT);
    DescriptorExtractor de2 = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SIFT);
    de1.compute(test_mat1,mkp1,desc1 );//提取sift特征
    de2.compute(test_mat2,mkp2,desc2 );//提取sift特征

    MatOfDMatch matches  = new MatOfDMatch();
    DescriptorMatcher dm =  DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);
    dm.match(desc1, desc2, matches);

    int  size=matches.cols()*matches.rows();
    double si=size;
    DMatch []darray =new DMatch [size];
    darray=matches.toArray();
    DMatch d=new DMatch();

    double max_dist = 0;
    double min_dist = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        double dist = darray[i].distance;
        //System.out.println(dist);

        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    //筛选出较好的匹配点
    List goodMatches=new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (darray[i].distance <=0.31 * max_dist)
        {
            goodMatches.add(darray[i]);
        }
    }
    double ans=goodMatches.size()/si;

    if(goodMatches!=null)
    System.out.println( "matches:   "+size+"     goodMatcher:   "+goodMatches.size() +"       percent1:     "+ans); 
    test_mat1.release();
    test_mat2.release();
    desc1.release();
    desc2.release();
    goodMatches.clear();
    return ans;
}

//提取sift特征矩阵
public Mat sift(String path)
{
    Mat test_mat1  = Highgui.imread(path);
    //System.out.println(test_mat1.height());
    //Imgproc.resize(test_mat1, test_mat1, new Size(544,128));
    Mat desc1 = new Mat();

    FeatureDetector fd1 = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);//创建特征描述子
    //FeatureDetector fd1 = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.
    MatOfKeyPoint mkp1 =new MatOfKeyPoint();

    fd1.detect(test_mat1, mkp1);
    DescriptorExtractor de1 = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SIFT);

    de1.compute(test_mat1,mkp1,desc1 );//提取sift特征
    test_mat1.release();
    mkp1.release();
    return desc1;
}


//颜色直方图比较
public double compareHist(String trainPicture,String testPicture)
{                                                                                   
     //System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
     List<Mat> imgaesList1=new ArrayList<>();
     List<Mat> imgaesList2=new ArrayList<>();
     new Highgui();
        Mat img1 = Highgui.imread(trainPicture);
     new Highgui();
        Mat img2 = Highgui.imread(testPicture);  
     imgaesList1.add(img1);
     imgaesList2.add(img2);

     int channelArray[]={0,1,2};
     MatOfInt channels=new MatOfInt(channelArray);
     Mat hist1=new Mat();
     Mat hist2=new Mat();
     MatOfInt histSize=new MatOfInt(256, 256, 256);

     MatOfFloat ranges=new MatOfFloat(0.0f,255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f);

     //MatOfInt histSize=new MatOfInt(1, 1, 1)
     //MatOfFloat ranges=new MatOfFloat(0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

     Imgproc.calcHist(imgaesList1, channels,new Mat(), hist1, histSize, ranges);
     Imgproc.calcHist(imgaesList2, channels,new Mat(), hist2, histSize, ranges);
     //Core.normalize(hist1, hist1);
     //Core.normalize(hist2, hist2);

     double cmp1 = Imgproc.compareHist(hist1, hist2, Imgproc.CV_COMP_CORREL);
     cmp1 = Math.abs(cmp1);
     //double cmp2 = Imgproc.compareHist(hist1, hist2, Imgproc.CV_COMP_INTERSECT);
     //cmp2 = Math.abs(cmp2);
     //double ans = Math.sqrt(cmp1*cmp2);
     img1.release();
     img2.release();
     hist1.release();
     hist2.release();
     imgaesList1.clear();
     imgaesList2.clear();
     return cmp1;
}


public Mat compareHist(String path)
{
     System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
     List<Mat> imgaesList1=new ArrayList<>();
     new Highgui();
     Mat img1 = Highgui.imread(path);
     imgaesList1.add(img1);
     int channelArray[]={0,1,2};
     MatOfInt channels=new MatOfInt(channelArray);
     Mat hist1 =new Mat();
     //hist1.create(new Size(256,256), CvType.CV_32FC1);
     MatOfInt histSize=new MatOfInt(256, 256, 256);
     MatOfFloat ranges=new MatOfFloat(0.0f,255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f);
     Imgproc.calcHist(imgaesList1, channels,new Mat(), hist1, histSize, ranges);

     //hist1, 3维矩阵，元素类型为32FC1, 尺寸256*256，
     Core.normalize(hist1, hist1);
     Imgproc.resize(hist1, hist1, new Size(256,256));
     hist1.convertTo(hist1, CvType.CV_32FC1);   
     img1.release(); 
     imgaesList1.clear();
    /*
    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
    IplImage srcImg=cvLoadImage("pictures//rose1.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow("Test");
    cvShowImage("Test",srcImg);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(srcImg);
    cvDestroyWindow("Text");*/
     return hist1;
}


//连接本地sqlserver数据库
public void sqlConnect()
{
     try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ResultSet rs = null; //操作结果
        try {

             String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; DatabaseName=mydata";
             String sSQL="select * from myappdata ";
             String username="sa";
             String password="521521";
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, password);
              Statement statement = con.createStatement();
              rs = statement.executeQuery(sSQL);


              int count=0;
              ID =new int[number];
              flowerName =new String[number];
              flowerNumber =new int[number];
              fileAddress =new String[number];
              score =new double [number];
              MaxscoreFlower =new String[3];
              while(rs.next())
              {
                  count++;
                  ID[count]=count;
                  flowerName[count]=rs.getString("flower name"); 
                  fileAddress[count]=Path+rs.getString("file address"); 
                  //System.out.println(fileAddress[count]);
              }
           statement.close();
                con.close(); 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}


//连接sae数据库
public void sqlConnectOnline()
{
        ResultSet rs = null; //操作结果
        try {

            String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://w.rdc.sae.sina.com.cn:3307/app_identification";  
            String Username=SaeUserInfo.getAccessKey();
            String Password=SaeUserInfo.getSecretKey();
            String Driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            try {
                Class.forName(Driver).newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,Username,Password);
            //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("SAE_MYSQL_DB","SAE_MYSQL_USER", "SAE_MYSQL_PASS");
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from myappdata");

              int count=0;
              ID =new int[number];
              flowerName =new String[number];
              flowerNumber =new int[number];
              fileAddress =new String[number];
              score =new double [number];
              while(rs.next())
              {
                  count++;
                  ID[count]=count;
                  flowerName[count]=rs.getString("flower name"); 
                  fileAddress[count]=rs.getString("file address"); 

              }
           statement.close();
                con.close(); 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
/*
public static void main(String []args)
{
    opencvtest t=new opencvtest("testpictures\\dandelion2.jpg",1,2);
}
*/

}
```

What should I do if I want it to run at a web service not just at my personal computer?

Thank you.

Comment: there will be **no way** with gae (they won't let you install any binaries)